# actualizar un campo de una tabla desde otra

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla donde se guardan los campos Puerto y cliente , quiero actualiza otra tabla llamada Puertos_cto donde el puerto de la tabla de origen sea igual al de tabla Puertos_ctos se le agregue el al campo cliente el registro que se guardo en la otra tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que lo que quieres es un trigger que actualice una tabla en cuanto se cambien los campos de otra, ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la sentencia **UPDATE** en combinación con una subconsulta que haga la selección de los registros adecuados. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
UPDATE Puertos_cto
SET cliente = (
    SELECT cliente
    FROM tabla_origen
    WHERE tabla_origen.Puerto = Puertos_cto.puerto
)
WHERE puerto IN (
    SELECT puerto
    FROM tabla_origen
);
```

En este ejemplo:

**Puertos_cto** es la tabla objetivo que deseas actualizar.

**tabla_origen** es la tabla de donde quieres obtener los datos para actualizar **Puertos_cto**.
Estamos actualizando el campo cliente en **Puertos_cto** utilizando una subconsulta para obtener el valor correspondiente de **tabla_origen**.

El primer **SELECT** en la subconsulta busca el valor de cliente en **tabla_origen** donde los puertos coincidan.

El **UPDATE** se realiza solo en los registros de **Puertos_cto** que tengan un puerto correspondiente en la subconsulta.

Asegúrate de reemplazar **Puertos_cto** y **tabla_origen** con los nombres reales de tus tablas y ajustar los nombres de los campos según corresponda en tu esquema de base de datos. Además, antes de realizar cambios masivos en la base de datos, siempre es recomendable hacer una copia de seguridad para evitar pérdida de datos en caso de errores.

Comment: Lo voy a intentar, muchas gracias